# Building minimal cython file with python 3.3 (Anaconda) under windows 7

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7, cython, anaconda

When I try to build a minimal Cython file test.pyx with Python 3.3 (Anaconda 3) under windows 7, I obtain a strange error:

```
C:\Users\myname\Test_cython>python setup.py build
running build
running build_ext
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Of course test.pyx is in the working directory. It works fine under windows with Python 2.7 (Anaconda) and under Linux with Python 2 and 3.

What could be the problem here with Python 3.3 (Anaconda 3)?

Thanks

The file setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

setup(
    name = 'test',
    cmdclass = {"build_ext": build_ext},
    ext_modules = [Extension('test', ['test.pyx'])]
    )
```

**Solution:**

I found that the line 404 of the file cygwinccompiler.py of the package disutils

```
out_string = check_output(['gcc', '-dumpmachine'])
```

has to be changed as

```
out_string = check_output(['gcc', '-dumpmachine'], shell=True)
```

Then, it compiles normally.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The line 404 of the file cygwinccompiler.py of the package disutils

```
out_string = check_output(['gcc', '-dumpmachine'])
```

has to be changed as

```
out_string = check_output(['gcc', '-dumpmachine'], shell=True)
```

Then, it compiles normally.