# pyd modules build failed with ld.exe complaining [def_file].def:1: syntax error

Tags: python, build, anaconda, python-3.6, mingw-w64

I am using anaconda py3.6, with conda's mingw32.

I set mingw32 as the compiler, also modified cygwinccompiler.py as suggested in [Building minimal cython file with python 3.3 (Anaconda) under windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291506/building-minimal-cython-file-with-python-3-3-anaconda-under-windows-7) .

Now I still can't build any binary pyd module, they all failed at the linking step with similar error.

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\gcc.bat -shared -s build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\cymysql\packet.o build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\cymysql\packet.cp36-win32.def -LC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\libs -LC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\PCbuild\win32 -lpython36 -lmsvcr140 -o build\lib.win32-3.6\cymysql\packet.cp36-win32.pyd c:/programdata/anaconda3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\cymysql\packet.cp36-win32.def:1: syntax error
c:/programdata/anaconda3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\cymysql\packet.cp36-win32.def: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
c:/programdata/anaconda3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\cymysql\packet.cp36-win32.def:1: syntax error
 collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status error: command 'C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\Scripts\\gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1
```

another example:

```
(base) D:\pymssql-build\pymssql>gcc -shared -s build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_mssql.o build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_mssql.cp36-win32.def -LC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\lib -LC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Library\lib -LD:\pymssql-build\pymssql\freetds\ming_32\lib-nossl -LC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\libs -LC:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\PCbuild\win32 -llibiconv -liconv -lsybdb -lws2_32 -lwsock32 -lkernel32 -lpython36 -lmsvcr140 -o build\lib.win32-3.6\_mssql.cp36-win32.pyd
c:/programdata/anaconda3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_mssql.cp36-win32.def:1: syntax error
c:/programdata/anaconda3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_mssql.cp36-win32.def: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
c:/programdata/anaconda3/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.0/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:build\temp.win32-3.6\Release\_mssql.cp36-win32.def:1: syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

While the def files looks just fine to me:

```
LIBRARY _mssql.cp36-win32.pyd
EXPORTS
PyInit__mssql
```

_mssql.o  size: 507kb